# C - Array of words

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm fairly new to programming, so sorry if this question seems trivial. I have looked for the answer, but I can't get a straight one. We've covered this in class, but my brain is just completely failing me right now .

In C, I need to make an array so that each element corresponds to a word.

**EDIT:** I just remembered I should do something with a pointer array. So something like this is what I'm doing...

```
main()
{
    char *line[MAXLINE];   // This points to the beginning of words in compare[]
    char compare[MAXLINE]; // This is where the words will be read in
    int  counter[MAXLINE]; // Counter for the words that appear more than once
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    int n;

    for (n=0; c!=EOF; n++){
        while ((c=getchar())!=' '||c!='\n'||c!=EOF){
            compare[i]=c;
            i++;
        }
        line[n]=compare;
        i = 0;
    }
```

I'm aware that's not the whole thing because I need to make compare have a new address, how would one suggest going about doing that? Do I need to use structs or is there another way? Should I be using malloc for that?

I apologize if I asked a stupid question. Since this is my first post here, any input on the way I went about asking this question is greatly appreciated since I already respect this community incredibly and would not want to ruin it with silly questions. Oh, input on the question itself is also appreciated :)

Thanks,
Slashstar

Comment: If this is homework, you should edit the tags to say so.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`scanf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf) and a `do..while` loop:

```
int counter = 0, i;
int length = 15;
char *wordz[length];

do {
    printf("Enter word number %d:", counter+1);
    char *temp = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    scanf("%s", temp);
    if(temp) {
        wordz[counter++] = temp;
    }       
} while(counter < length);

for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("\nWord number %d is %s", i+1, wordz[i]);
    free(wordz[i]); //we malloc'd in the do statement above, so we must free the memory...
}
```

***For the record, this solution works.***

#### Screenshot: (set length variable to 5 in this case)

[image]

Comment: `words` should be `wordz` and it's already an array of pointers. So there is no need of `&`.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with scanf. Could you explain how that code you wrote works?

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for the wordz, just for the pointers.

Comment: @user527179 Hows this possible?..that you are working with pointers and you are not familiar with scanf..just curious

Comment: Welp, our class is going through K&R C Programming Language and that's in chapter 7. Pointers are chapter 5.

Comment: That looks better! I just tested it myself. Thanks a lot Jacob!

Comment: @Jacob: `temp` is of size `1` and you are reading a word into into.

Comment: Thanks codaddict... I was wondering why my code wasn't working =\

Comment: How would you go about doing this if you didn't know how many words you wanted to answer...?

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work (linux) for windows you need to remove \r as well at end

```
char buf[MAXLINE];
char** wordsz = malloc( MAXNUMBEROFWORDS * sizeof(char*) );
int wordCount = 0;
while (fgets( buf, MAXLINE, stdin )!=NULL && wordCount<MAXNUMBEROFWORDS)
{
   int len = strlen(buf); 
   if ( buf[len-1] == '\n' ) buf[len-1]='\0';
   wordsz[wordCount] = malloc( strlen(buf) + 1 );// assuming sizeof(char)==1 + \0
   strcpy(wordsz[wordCount++], buf);
}
```

fgets returns NULL when you press EOF, you cannot overwrite memory if enter too long string as with scanf and you are only allocating space that you actually need (part from the MAXNUMBEROFWORDS)

Comment: This looks very clean! Thanks for an alternate approach! No idea why people are downvoting you :(